# $\mathcal{C}$-filtering of modules inherited by submodules

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory

I'll state the question about modules, but I'm open to examples in other contexts.  I am not an algebraist, so please forgive any non-conventional terminology.

**DEFINITION:**  Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a collection of (countable) modules (for some fixed ring).  Given a module $M$ of size $\omega_1$, let's say that $M$ is "strongly $\mathcal{C}$-filtered" iff there is a $\subseteq$-increasing and continuous sequence $\langle M_i \ : \ i < \omega_1 \rangle$ of countable submodules, with union M, such that $M_i \in \mathcal{C}$ and $M_j / M_i \in \mathcal{C}$ whenever $i < j < \omega_1$.

**QUESTION:**  What are some nontrivial examples of classes $\mathcal{C}$ that have the following ``inheritance" property:  whenever $|M|=\omega_1$ and $M$ is strongly $\mathcal{C}$-filtered, then every submodule of $M$ of size $\omega_1$ is also strongly $\mathcal{C}$-filtered?

The only example I'm aware of is where $\mathcal{C}$ is the collection of (countable) free abelian groups (i.e. countable free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules).  In this situation, for an abelian group $M$ of size $\omega_1$, it's easy to see that $M$ is strongly $\mathcal{C}$-filtered if and only if $M$ is free.  And, since subgroups of free abelian groups are always free, $\mathcal{C}$ has the inheritance property requested in the question.

(More generally, $\mathcal{C}$ = "the set of all countable free $R$-modules", where $R$ is a PID, works for the same reason, since submodules of free modules are free if the ring is a PID.  Of course in these examples, one could just as well let $\mathcal{C} = \{ F_\omega \}$ where $F_\omega$ is the free object on a countably infinite set of generators.  But in the question I don't necessarily require that $\mathcal{C}$ be a singleton, or even a countable, collection).

Comment: Whitehead's Problem comes to mind...

Comment: I would be interested in knowing if Whitehead groups of size $\omega_1$ can be characterized by strong $\mathcal{C}$-filtering, for some $\mathcal{C}$ that satisfies the requirements of the question (assuming we're in a universe where there is a non-free Whitehead group, of course).

Comment: Well, in the proof that $\lozenge$ implies that every Whitehead group is free there is a characterization of what and where things fail. To my understanding that was the origin of club guessing, too.